Nature of unbounded initials in polynomial symplectic maps
Is the following statement true? How it can be proved/rejected?
Initial conditions that correspond to unbounded orbits in polynomial symplectic mappings, which exhibit chaotic behavior (exponential sensitivity), yield chaotic trajectories, except in the case of periodic fixed points.
